# Should sink overflow be full of water?

Tags: water, sink, overflow

I had one of those bowl sinks fitted about a year ago, by a proper bathroom fitter (*through Wickes*). It was [This One](https://www.diy.com/departments/goodhome-blanca-round-counter-mounted-counter-top-basin/1618571_BQ.prd)

I was cleaning it the other day and I took the overflow cover off and found that the water level is right up just below the hole.

Is that normal?

Edit - attaching second image. I'm guessing the marked bit is where the overflow might attach?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is that normal?

NO, It should not be full of water. It's purpose is to drain water that flows into it so water does not spill over the top of the sink and on the floor.

There is channel that the overflow water flows through to an opening in the drain. (*If the proper drain with an opening was installed, some are not designed for an overflow*).  If the installer used plumbers putty it is possible that the openings got clogged.

If you take the stopper out you should be able see the opening on the side of drain hole and possibly see if the hole is obstructed.

Comment: Not all drains have the opening for an overflow.  It might be the wrong style drain!

Comment: @SteveWellens Good point, i edited that into my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've had a quick look in the unit under the sink, and I can only see the main pipe coming through the worktop. The overflow on my kitchen sink has a little pipe connecting it to the s bend thing, should this sink have something similar?

Comment: @danwellman kitchen sinks in the UK usually have an external pipe for the overflow, Hand basins on the other hand usually have the overflow internally.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added another pic from inside the unit the sink sits on. But if the overflow is internal I guess it should flow into the main outlet and connect up inside the sink somehow? Probably I will have to get the sink off the unit and look at the bottom

Comment: The sink you have has an internal overflow channel cast into it. It would not be plumbed to the fitting in your new photo. The tail piece you have attached to the bottom of your sink may not, *Probably is not*,   the proper one for the sink you have. *I do not recognize  the plumbing pieces in your photo*.

Comment: Ok, thanks @AlaskaMan I had a go at removing the plughole cover yesterday, but it's one of the popup plugs (push to plug, push again to open) and I can't get it off. Guess I'll have to get the whole sink off to see if the overflow bit is blocked

Answer (score 2):

As said already, there should be no water in the overflow. The presence of water means that it is blocked.

The bit marked with a `??` is an anti-syphon valve. It's not designed to be connected to anything.

The overflow connection will be inside the main waste, which should have a slot in in to allow water through, like the picture below. Note the sq

[image: Basin main waset connection with hole]

I had a similar problem with my sink when I bought my house (I'm in the UK also) - the previous owner had clearly had a leaking seal under the sink (the lower rubber washer in the picture above), and decided to try and fix it with silicone sealant, which blocked the hole for the overflow in the process.

You would also have the issue if the sink was installed with a waste which does not have the overflow inlet in it. If this is the case then there is no way for the water to flow out into the drain, and it will sit their and stagnate.

Have a look down the drain and see if you can see an openning for the overflow - the hole should be visible and should be at the back of the basin. If there is no hole, you will need to remove the basin and replace the waste insert.

Comment: Thanks, I had a go at removing the plughole cover yesterday, but it's one of the popup plugs (push to plug, push again to open) and I can't get it off. Guess I'll have to get the whole sink off to see if the overflow bit is blocked

Comment: @danwellman if it's anything like mine (see update picture in post), the popup part simply turns anti-clockwise and unscrews

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to replace one part with something like the below (it has an extra port), then fit a tube on it and the sink overflow.

The port comes from the shop blocked up (like second picture) and has to be opened before joining pipe.

[image]

[image]